# Reveal linear regression slopes one at a time using gganimate and ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, linear-regression, gganimate

The below code makes a plot of the actual slope (the red line)  produced by running linear regression using the entire `mtcars` data. The plot also shows all the slopes produced by using subsets of `mtcars` (black lines).

But how can I show the slopes produced using subsets of `mtcars` (the black lines) one at a time using `gganimate`?

Also, the abline is has been drawn below the minimum value of `mtcars$drat` and above the maximum value of `mtcars$drat`. How can I make the abline stop at the minimum and maximum values?

#### Make tibble

```
library(tibble); library(dplyr); library(purrr); library(ggplot2); library(gganimate)

tibble(actual.slope = lm(mpg ~ drat, mtcars)$coef[2], actual.intercept = lm(mpg ~ drat, mtcars)$coef[1]) -> 
  mtcars_slopes

sample_slope <- function() {
  mtcars %>% 
    slice_sample(prop = 0.5, replace = TRUE) ->
    mtcars_sample
    
  lm(mpg ~ drat, mtcars_sample)$coef[2] -> sample.slope
  lm(mpg ~ drat, mtcars_sample)$coef[1] -> sample.intercept
  
  tibble(sample.slope, sample.intercept)
}

purrr::map_df(1:1000, function(x) sample_slope()) -> df

cbind(mtcars_slopes, df) -> mtcars_slopes
```

#### Plot

```
ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(drat, mpg), color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1, alpha = 1) +
  geom_abline(slope = mtcars_slopes$actual.slope, intercept = mtcars_slopes$actual.intercept, colour = "red", alpha = 1, size = 1.5) +
  geom_abline(slope = mtcars_slopes$sample.slope, intercept = mtcars_slopes$sample.intercept, colour = "black", alpha = 0.02)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is how it works:

```
library(gganimate)
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_point(data = mtcars, aes(drat, mpg), color = "black", fill = NA, size = 1, alpha = 1) +
  geom_abline(aes(slope = sample.slope, intercept = sample.intercept), color = "black", alpha = 0.2) +
  theme_bw()+
  labs(title = "Sample Slope: {closest_state}") +
  transition_states(cumsum(!is.na(sample.slope)), 
                    transition_length = 0.5,
                    state_length = 1,
                    wrap = FALSE) +
  shadow_mark()+
  ease_aes('linear')+
  geom_abline(aes(slope = mtcars_slopes$actual.slope, 
                  intercept = mtcars_slopes$actual.intercept), 
              color = "red", alpha = 1, size = 1.5)
```

[image]